How to achieve max(column_a) keep (dense_rank last order by column_b) in databricks?
I have a sql in oracle that I need to convert to databricks. Is there a databricks equivalent to the
max() keep (dense_rank order by)?
select
id,
max(column_a) keep (dense_rank last order by column_b) 
group by id;


Please produce a [mcve] by adding sample input and expected output.

Can you try:
SELECT distinct
id,
last_value(column_a) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY column_b) AS 
column_a_max
FROM your_table

can you explain how that differs from your needs? give example data input and expected output.

Databricks supports the row_number analytic function, you could use:
SELECT id,
       column_a AS max_b_a
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         column_a,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY id ORDER BY column_b DESC, column_a DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  rn = 1;

Which, for the sample Oracle data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, column_a, column_b) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 2 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
MAX_B_A




1
3


2
4


3
1



Which is the same as the query:
select id,
       max(column_a) keep (dense_rank last order by column_b) AS max_b_a
FROM   table_name
group by id;

Note: I do not have a Databricks installation to test against so the comparison was done in Oracle - you may need to fix some syntax differences between the two applications but based on the documentation it should work.
fiddle
